# Getting this error while converting lead via trigger:Illegal assignment from List<LeadStatus> to LeadStatus at line 25 column 24

Tags: apex, trigger, lead-conversion

Illegal assignment from List to LeadStatus at line 25 column 24

```
 public with sharing class ConvertonQualifiedStageHandler {
    Set<Id> setLeadID = new Set<Id>();
    public void onInsertUpdate(List<Lead> lstTriggerLeads){

    for(Lead objLead : lstTriggerLeads)
    {
        if(objLead.Status =='Qualified')
        {
            setLeadID .add(objLead.Id);
        }            
    }
    convertLead(setLeadID);                      
    }

    public void convertLead(Set<Id> setLeadID)
    {
        for(Id objLeadId : setLeadID)
        {
            Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
            lc.setLeadId(objLeadId);

            LeadStatus status= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
            lc.setConvertedStatus(status.MasterLabel);

            Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
            //System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: Do you have a class called `LeadStatus` in your code base? If so you can ensure that the SObject name is used here as you intend by using `Schema.LeadStatus status = ...`.

Comment: @KeithC nice catch. Spend 3 days once with same problem for StaticResource class

Comment: you can also put the query outside for loop. it doesn't require in loop also its a bad practicse

Answer (score 0):

Are you quering for LeadStats anywhere else in your code? It seems the lead conversion is firing the lead trigger (or the account/contact/opportunity trigger) and there is a query for LeadStatus where there might not be a limit 1 specified. You can try by replacing

```
lc.setConvertedStatus(status.MasterLabel);
```

with

```
lc.setConvertedStatus('My Converted Status');
```

If it still gives the same error, most definitely there is another query on LeadStatus somewhere else.